# Jbutton multiple clicks

Tags: java, swing, click, double, jbutton

So I am creating a game of checkers, using a grid of 8x8 JButtons. I want to click on a JButton (all of the action listeners are set up), and upon clicking of the button, be able to click on another button located diagonally from the button. I have all the legal moves worked out, I just do not know how to set it up so I can only click on a button directly diagonal from the piece I previously clicked.

I hope this makes sense and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you identify each button with a proper ID or position, you can calculate which button(s) need to be clickable.

```
Col  : A B C D E F G H
----------------------
Row 1: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
Row 2: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
Row 3: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

This is only a 3 by 8, but, depending on which player you are, you can determine moves by `firstClickRowNum-1 AND (firstClickColNum=firstClickColNum+1 || firstClickColNum=firstClickColNum--)` as you said you've already done.

You'll then want to create a method called disableOtherButtons() which will call `JButton.setEnabled(false);` for each button that is not in the previous set. I suggest you have a ArrayList (or some other collection object) of buttons so you can iterate over them.